# CSS user-select: none causes focus event on drag in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

Google Chrome makes **input** / **textarea** focused on **drag** if it is located in container with `-webkit-user-select: none;`

See example http://jsfiddle.net/kdrz4r0p/1/

Steps to reproduce:

- Add `-webkit-user-select: none;` to container
- drag any element in this container to the textarea/input

Also I have found same issue in chromium bugtracker:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=376767

Does anybody know rough solution for this issue?
I need to prevent this focuse event (by dragging). Because I expand textarea by focus.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? It's still an issue.

Comment: Any news on this ?

Answer (score -2):

Add ***outline*** property.

```
textarea {
    width: 100px;
    height: 250px;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I poorly explained my goal. You provide solution which removes visual effect of focuse. But I need to prevent focuse event! I just expand my textarea by focus. Thank you for response.